# Video Recording (expo -camera) is not working on production/apk file but work my local

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, expo-camera

1

I'm using an expo-camera for video recording in my react native app. Everything is working great in development but when I generate an APK file so the camera is not recording the video.

```
`type here`
```

Answer (score 0):

just Add these line in your app.json

`"android": {"permissions": ["AUDIO_RECORD"]}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).